# dynamically close and open table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table on my site that contains the options for different products. I didn't put it there, the ecommerce platform did. It lists the options in a row in the table. The table looks like this:

```
<div class="attributes">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Size:</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><select><option>Sizes here</option></select></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then if there were another option it would be in an additional row with the same markup.

This renders with the label (size in this case) out in front of the `<select>` box. I want the label above the `<select>` box and I figured the easiest way to accomplish this would be to close the `<tr>` and open a new one. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT: I should mention that the ecommerce platform generates the html and I do not have access to the source code

Comment: are you able to modify the html?

Comment: @esdot no the source code is not available to me

Comment: What can you do then? You seem to have illustrated your problem without any possible solution since you can't modify anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it follows that exact structure, try this:

```
$(".attributes select").each(function(){
    $label = $(this).parent().prev().prev();
    $label.parent().before("<tr></tr>");
    $label.parent().prev().append($label.clone());
    $label.remove();
    $(this).parent().prev().remove();
});
```

Here's an example: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U7s8e/)

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks a ton, you've saved me hours of hair pulling!

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```
<div class="attributes">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Size:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><select><option>Sizes here</option></select></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thats what I want the html to end up like, yes, but it isn't as simple as just recoding the html. The ecommerce platform generates this code from a database and I don't have access to the source code

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do it in two steps:

1. remove the elements:

> ```
> $('.attributes').find('tr:first-child').remove();
>
> $('.attributes').find('tr:first-child').remove();
> ```

2.append them back in the same place

```
$('.attributes').find('tr:first-child').before('<tr><td>Sizes here</td></tr>');
```